# JAVA Unable to GET File from REST service

Tags: java, rest, jersey-client

I have a source of which I try to get a file via rest. I think I have everything I need. The url, name, pass, correct encoding etc.
When I query the file with the tool 'Postman' it works fine. Only in my JAVA code do I always get an exception.
My Code:

```
String urlTo = "https://mylink/file.zip";
String auth = "myUser:myPass"

String authEnc = new BASE64Encoder().encode(auth.getBytes());
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource(urlTo);

ClientResponse resp = webResource.accept("application/zip")
                .header("Authorization", "Basic" + authStringEnc)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/zip")
                .get(ClientResponse.class);
```

When I run the code I get the following exception:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:670)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:503)
```

The path to the certificate does not seem to be found, I just do not understand why

Thanx for help :)

Comment: Do you have the certificate properly set up and configured for java?

Comment: ok, i'm not really familiar with how the certificate works. But I have somewhere read that the path to the certificate must explicitly set. I tried System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "... \ Java \ jre1.8.0_181 \ lib \ security \ cacerts"). that did not help

Comment: you should have the certificate downloaded from the webservice.

Comment: As it is a HTTPS request from which you are trying to download the file. You need to install the webservice certificate. You can download the certificate via mozilla firefox.

Comment: many thanks for your help. I have now downloaded and installed the certificate from the webservice. In the browser it works like expected but still not in my java code. Now I read that I should add the certificate to the JAVA keystore. That's what I did and tested. Certificate has been added to the keystore.
But still I get the same error again when I run the Java code. It is to despair